# Date Class - Method to figure out day of the week of the Date object that calls it

Tags: python, class, oop, object, methods

I built a Date Class that has a tomorrow method, add_n_days method, equals method, before and after methods, and a difference method. What I'm trying to figure out is how to use my difference method to create a new method where I figure out the day of the week the Date object falls on.

```
 # A class to represent calendar dates
 #

class Date:
""" A class that stores and manipulates dates,
    represented by a day, month, and year.
"""

# The constructor for the Date class.
def __init__(self, new_month, new_day, new_year):
    """ The constructor for objects of type Date. """
    self.month = new_month
    self.day = new_day
    self.year = new_year

# The function for the Date class that returns a Date
# object in a string representation.
def __repr__(self):
    """ This method returns a string representation for the
        object of type Date that it is called on (named self).

        ** Note that this _can_ be called explicitly, but
          it more often is used implicitly via printing or evaluating.
    """
    s = '%02d/%02d/%04d' % (self.month, self.day, self.year)
    return s

def is_leap_year(self):
    """ Returns True if the called object is
        in a leap year. Otherwise, returns False.
    """
    if self.year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    elif self.year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    elif self.year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def copy(self):
    """ Returns a new object with the same month, day, year
        as the called object (self).
    """
    new_date = Date(self.month, self.day, self.year)
    return new_date

def is_before(self,d2):
    if self.year<d2.year:
        return true 
    if self.month<d1.month and self.year==d2.year:
        return True
    if self.day < d2.day and d2.month == self.month and self.year ==d2.year:
        return true
    return False

def is_after(self,d2): 
    return d2.isbefore(self)


def diff(self,d2):
    dcopy=self.copy()
    difference=0
    if dcopy.isbefore(d2) == True:
        while dcopy.isBefore(d)==true:
        dcopy.tomorrow()
        difference-=1
    else:
        while dcopy.isafter(d2):
            dcopy.yesterday()
            difference +=1

    return difference


def diff(self,d2):
    dcopy=self.copy()
    difference=0
    while dcopy.isbefore(d2):
        dcopy.tomorrow()
        difference-=1
    while dcopy.isafter(d2):
        dcopy.yesterday()
        difference+=1
```

The way I am thinking of implementing it, but don't really understand how to establish it concretely is having a known date, a list with the Weekdays, using a modulus operator when trying to figure out the day of the weeks - %=7, and the diff (difference) method from above.

What is my best way of going about this problem, I would appreciate any help, explanation - I'm new to python and OOP.

Thanks.

day_of_week_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                            'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

output in shell, I think should look like this

```
>>> d = Date(4, 4, 2016)
>>> d.day_of_week()
'Monday'
>>> Date(1, 1, 2100).day_of_week()
'Friday'
>>> Date(7, 4, 1776).day_of_week()
'Thursday'
```

Comment: Much as I hate to ask, is there any reason you are not using python's built-in [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)? The weekday() method should handle this for you.

Comment: @ChrisC73 trying to learn about classes and methods - just to wrap my head around it :)

Answer (score 3):

If I told you that 1/1/2000 was a Monday and asked you what day of the week was 50 days later, it would be easy to figure out.

It's simply 50 % 7, which is 1. Therefore, we know that the day of the week we are looking at is one day past the day we know.

So 50 days later would be a Tuesday, or 1 day past Monday.

Since you can find out how many days are between any given date and a so-called anchor date (like the 1/1/2000 example I gave above), you can calculate the day of the week for any date.

Comment: +1 since the method also goes backwards with little modification (-50 % 7 gives 6, check if the first is negative and negate)

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudo code, cited from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Other_purely_mathematical_algorithms) should help you get started. It depends on integer division, so remember to use `//` in python to get 'c-like' integer division.

```
def day_of_week(self):
     d, m, y = self.day, self.month, self.year
     day_of_week_names = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
     t = [0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4]
     if m < 3:
          y -= 1
     index = (y + y//4 - y//100 + y//400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7
     return day_of_week_names[index]
```